# Picking the next value of a column where the last occurrence of a particular value found in a different column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
date        buys/    quantity   Rolling Sum
            sell
08-AUG-19   BUY      100       -
13-SEP-19   SELL    -100       0
26-SEP-19   BUY      200      200
28-SEP-19   SELL    -50       150
29-SEP-19   SELL    -150       0
```

I need to have the last date of buy after the recent full sold out state of the quantity.

In the above case it sold out twice once on 13-sep-19 and second one was on 29-sep-19 as an output i need to have the value as 26-sep-19 (as this was the latest buy before the recent sold out state)

Expected result:

```
26-sep-19
```

Comment: Specify the expected result set.

Comment: Where does c/c# come into this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 26-sep-19 should be the output

Answer (score 1):

> get the latest buy before the recent sold out state

Here is one option:

```
select max(date)
from mytable t
where 
    buy_sell = 'BUY'
    and date < (
        select max(date) 
        from mytable 
        where rolling_sum = 0 and buy_sell = 'SELL'
)
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28d1de05a71de6dac267c08433949b50)** with your sample data returns:

```
| max(date)  |
| :--------- |
| 2019-09-26 |
```

Note: this assumes

1) that you are storing dates as a dateè-like datatype, not as strings...

2) that the `rolling_sum` is an actual column in your table

Comment: That's what I assumed too, but I have a sneaking suspicion rolling_sum isn't an actual column in the OP's table

Comment: @Pepper: ah you maybe right. I added a mention about that in my answer.